# Regular expression to find multiple words in string

Tags: regex

I need to extract multiple words from the string in any order whether it exists or not.

For example, I want to extract `called, speak with, cust, customer, appointment, or car` from following lines.

> Called customer to inform the car is ready.
>   Customer called to check if the car is ready yet.
>   Called cust to notify his appointment.
>   Called customer to verify the insurance.
>   Spoke with the customer to remind her appointment.
>   Spoke with cust regarding her car's problem.

I tried this regex `(?=.*customer|cust)(?=.*car|appointment)(?=.*called|spoke with)` but it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say you want to extract any of those words, but you have grouped them together in pairs? Why are you using non-capturing groups if you want the words extracted? What language are you using the the regex in? Can you provide a code example of where you'd like to use the regex? Why are you prefixing the first word in every pair with `.*` (i.e. "any character, zero or more times")?

Answer (score 0):

To match any or a list of words/phrases, use an alternation `|`:

```
\b(called|speak with|cust|customer|appointment|car)\b
```

`\b` (word boundary) added at each end to stop `car` matching `carrot` etc.